# SqlAlchemy filter by subtable parameters?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was faced with the task of filtering products based on their characteristics.

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class Filter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'filter'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(ForeignKey("category.id"), nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    transcription = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    parent_category = relationship('Category', backref='filters')


class FilterParameter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fparameter'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    value = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    filter_id = Column(ForeignKey("filter.id"), nullable=False)
    transcription = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    filter = relationship('Filter', backref="fparams")


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    pic = Column(Text)
    price = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    availability = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    keywords = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class ProductParameter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pparameter'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    product_id = Column(ForeignKey("product.id"), nullable=False)
    value = Column(ForeignKey("fparameter.id"), nullable=False)

    product = relationship('Products', backref="pparams")
```

I have two groups of tables, with their own relationships. A category has its own filters, and filters have its own parameters.
The Product table has Parameters that are written in another table (ProductParameter) in the form of links to existing filter parameters.

Is there a way to filter Product by specific values ​​- FilterParameter_obj.transcription?

Approximately need to process such an expression.

Get list Products if: 'some transcription' in [ProductParameter_obj.value.transcription]
Where ProductParameter_obj.value = list of FilterParameter_objects

I've been looking for .filter and .join capabilities - but haven't seen a solution yet. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place)